# Clustering correlated variables in Gaussian Mixture Models

Tags: correlation, pca, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I would like to ask it dose not require to consider the correlation of variables if using Gaussian mixture model for clustering, because covariance has already been considered in the model. So the further question is that MFA (Multivariate Factor Analysis) adds rotation based on PCA (Principal Component Analysis), which can make variables after dimension reduced easier to explain but lose independence. Therefore, if the Gaussian mixture model does not need to consider the correlation of variables, can it indicate that the dataset is more suitable to use factor analysis instead of PCA before clustering?

Comment: A general Gaussian mixture model allows for correlations between variables.

Comment: thanks for answering!